# Manual triggering tooltip with delay ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I try to open / close a Tooltip via its parent div. Unfortunately, this does not work when using delay. Debugging my application shows, that manuel triggering `show()` or `close()` does not check for the delay.

Triggering it automatically handles it perfectly. As you can see in the reproduction,  I want to trigger the tooltip when you hover over the parent.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wh3uem?file=app/triggers-manual.html

Try to enter and leave the pink container fast. It will stick with the enabled Tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like manually triggering a Tooltip basically can not handle this feature. However, I implemented the delay-Functionality myself.

```js
// Check if there is currently an ongoing timeout
if(!this._runningTimeout) {
  this._runningTimeout = true;
  this._timeoutRef = setTimeout(() => {
    tooltip.show();
  }, 500);
} else {
  clearTimeout(this._timeoutRef);
  this._runningTimeout = false;
  tooltip.hide();
}
```

and trigger this function on `(mouseenter)="..."` and `(mouseleave)="..."` in the template.